# IF formula for greater than and less than in google sheets

Tags: if-statement, formula

I am trying to write a formula ie. if a cell value is within +3% to -3% then the cells should show as Active else Inactive. I have written a formula in excel and it works fine but in Sheets there seems to be some issue
Excel formula is"IF(AND(C5<=3%,C5>=-3%),"Active","Inactive")" Please help
Sheet Link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TsiImQNhIanWHAmKh0gLofASv1cSChGJh0lgW4cSklM/edit#gid=1261052156

Comment: I don't understand the question /the error. For me, it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(C6<=3%,C6>=-3%),"Active","Inactive")
```

here the cell C6 in formula is incorrect replace it with C5

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TsiImQNhIanWHAmKh0gLofASv1cSChGJh0lgW4cSklM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TsiImQNhIanWHAmKh0gLofASv1cSChGJh0lgW4cSklM/edit?usp=sharing